# Is it possible to add a separation line in WPF? (same as <hr/> in html)

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I would like to know if it is possible to have something equivalent to

---

in html in WPF.

It might be useful to visually separate commonly related form elements.

Any tip or suggestion on easiest way to achive is welcomed, I was thinking in a whole row with height=1 and colored background, but not sure if there is something more straightforward.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF has the Separator control that should be useful for what you need.

```
<Separator />
```

Here is the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.separator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Separator in MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Add a separator like Ignatus said or you can add a Rectangle with a Width or an Height of 1 pixel ( depend in the orientation you need) like this:

```
<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Blue" Height="1"/>
```

Another way is to group controls in different GroupBox which can have a border